# Unable to send SMS using telephony

Tags: flutter, sms, telephony

I have been trying to send SMS using telephony by following the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4yFdl3o1Lg. However, no message is being sent despite adding the required permissions.

```
  final SmsSendStatusListener listener = (SendStatus status) {
// Handle the status

 };

  final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
  

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    _sendSMS2() async {
       
        bool? permissionsGranted = await telephony.requestSmsPermissions;
        print(permissionsGranted);  //returns true
        bool? canSendSms = await telephony.isSmsCapable;
        print(canSendSms); //returns true
        // Get sim state
        SimState simState = await telephony.simState;
        print(simState);  //returns SimState.READY
        
        telephony.sendSms(to: "123456", message: "hello", statusListener: listener);
        
        }
      }
```

The status returns sendStatus.SENT but I don't find any message being sent.
I really need help, please.

Comment: Does the console output any error?

Comment: @EnviroApps no error on console. The canSendSms prints true and simState prints SimState.READY.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Did you check the documentation and example code of the Plugin available at: https://pub.dev/packages/telephony? Also this package only works on Android btw.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the following link. Sending SMS via the default SMS app works (telephony.sendSmsByDefaultApp(to: "1234567890", message: "Hi!"); but not by sending directly from the app. I don't understand why

Comment: @EnviroApps is there any other way than using telephony to send SMS directly without passing through default SMS app?

Comment: Although the statusListener returns SendStatus.SENT , I do not find any SMS being sent :(

Comment: @simsim try my answer below, gimme know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I removed the status listener and it then worked for me

```
telephony.sendSms(
      to: "123123",
      message: "May the force be with you! From MS",
      // statusListener: smsListener
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your phone number into international format. Then put `await` keyword for the method. This worked even i spam it many times.

```dart
onTap: () async {
   final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
   if (await telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions) {
      await telephony.sendSms(
         to: '62xxxxxxxxxxx',
         message: 'From flutter',
         statusListener: (s) => print(s.name),
      );
   }
}
```

screenshot
[image: screenshot.jpg]